# Is the use of indefinite article in this sentence wrong as my teacher said?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

My sentence is:

> Opened in 1982, the Rio Sul Center is **a** 164 meters high building.

But my teacher said the sentence should be:

> Opened in 1982, the Rio Sul Center is 164 meters high building.

(basically, removing the article ***a***). I still think that mine is correct, and hers is wrong.

Which one is correct, and why?

PS: English isn't my first language, that's why I'm asking this basic question.

Comment: I think probably English isn't your teacher's first language either. She's completely wrong - so far as I'm aware there's *no* dialectal variant where simply removing the article *(The Rio Sul Center is 164 meters high building)* results in an acceptable utterance. You'd have to remove the word ***building*** as well. This is *very* basic grammar, but I won't closevote for lack of prior research in case someone can explain *why* your teacher made such a ridiculous error (so it might be useful if you tell us what *her* native language is).

Comment: In short, your variant with "a" is correct. But I wouldn't tell your teacher that her variant is not correct.

Comment: Well, I can't really tell where she's from. I'm using EF English Live, so she may be from any country that have English as the first language. It was a writing exam where the system automatically assigns your text correction to a given teacher. Maybe, she didn't see the `building` in the end?

Comment: @Juan: Well, their website says you'll be learning [with the support of expert English teachers](http://englishlive.ef.com/en-gb/), so assuming you can still contact *that specific teacher*, I suggest you give her a chance to reconsider (perhaps you're right, and she simply didn't register the word *building*). If she still maintains that she's right, ask the company to sack her (perhaps they'll give you some free lessons by way of compensation! :)

Comment: The premodification required is _a 164-metre-high_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the answer by looking at the core of your sentence, removing all the qualifiers and subordinate clauses:

> The Center is a building.

Notice that this would not work at all without the article *a*.

Now as we add the supporting information back in, we see that we need to keep the article *a* at each stage:

> The Rio Sul Center is a building.
>
> Opened in 1982, the Rio Sul Center is a building.
>
> Opened in 1982, the Rio Sul Center is a 164-meters high building.

However, with that all said, your structuring of this sentence is still somewhat awkward, and difficult for a reader to parse, which is perhaps the root of your teacher's issue.  I might suggest one of the following alternatives.

> Opened in 1982, the Rio Sul Center is a building that is 164 meters high.
>
> The Rio Sul Center opened in 1982 and is 164 meters high.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, I think she was confused by the sentence, even thought it's correct.

Comment: @Juan: There really isn't anything "confusing" about your example from any native speaker's perspective - unless we consider the possibility of the word *building* not being noticed because it's on a separate line of text. That's how it appears to me on my screen, which *could* lead to "misparsing" simply because we don't expect *anything* after the word ***high*** (except perhaps a full stop, but you obviously wouldn't be looking for that on the next line, so if doesn't *immediately* follow *high*, you might simply assume it's been missed out).

Comment: No hyphen in the measure phrase following the copula.

Comment: Hi, cobaltduck. Opened in 1982, the Rio Sul Center is a 164-**meter** high building.